# How do i capture the second list on form submission

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have got a two level dynamic list.its working fine now the problem is that i am not able to capture second list value...i think you guys can help me ..

Here is form

```
    <?php
    require 'db.php';
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Selection Form</title>
     </head>

    <body>
    <form action="/display/check.php" method="get"/>

    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Select Semester</td>
        <td>
            <select id=semesterdd onChange="change_semester()" name="sem">

                <option>
                    Select
                </option>
                    <?php
                        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY semester ASC") or die($mysqli->error());
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

                        {
                            ?>
                            <option ><?php echo $row["semester"];?></option>

                            <?php
                        }   
                    ?>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Select Subjects:  
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="subjectid">
                <select name='sub'>
                    <option>
                        Select
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_semester()
        {

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax3.php?semester="+document.getElementById("semesterdd").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("subjectid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Here is the ajax file

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

$semester=$_GET["semester"];

if($semester!="")
{   
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE semester=$semester ORDER BY subject ASC") or die($mysqli->error());
    echo "<select>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    {

                echo "<option value=>";echo $row["subject"];echo "</option>";
                //echo '<option value="'.$row['code'].'">'.$row['subject'].'</option>';



    }   
    echo "</select>";
}   

?>
```

And here is the response..Its capturing the semester option but why not sub option?

```
http://127.0.0.1/display/check.php?sem=3
```

Comment: because your didn't pass it in? `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax3.php?semester="+document.getElementById("semesterdd").value,false);`

Comment: how to fix this?  i must get something like http://127.0.0.1/display/check.php?sem=3&sub=101

Comment: You've already done it for semesterdd, just do the same thing for your other parameter.

Comment: Can you help me out here ..I am just beginner in PHP..To be honest i got this code from elsewhere but now my entire work is stuck beacuse i cant read the subject seleection..I just need the second subject value to be passed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax3.php?semester="+document.getElement‌​ById("semesterdd").v‌​alue+"&sub="+document.getElement‌​ById("[subjectid]").v‌​alue,false);
```

change [subjectid] to whatever id you want for it.

Comment: i want the subjectid to be passed but it is showing me semester id thats the problem..http://127.0.0.1/display/check.php?sem=3

Comment: No.This is a dynamic list First user selects the semester based on that the  subjects for that semester is displayed in the second list.Now i need to know about final subject that is selected by the user...How to do that?